# Exception while trying to start the server using npm start command

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

After creating the app in vscode, I am unable to load the server port 3000. I am getting below exception

"app@0.1.0 start D:\React\app

> react-scripts start
>       Starting the development server...
>
> events.js:174
>             throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>             ^
>
> Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
>           at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>           at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>       Emitted 'error' event at:
>           at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
>           at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>       npm ERR! errno 1
>       npm ERR! app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 1`enter code here`
>       npm ERR!
>       npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 start script.
>       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users*******\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-05T17_08_42_058Z-debug.log"

Comment: paste the log from C:\Users*******\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-05T17_08_42_058Z-debug.log"

Answer (score 1):

Try delete node_modules folder install again with npm install

then npm cache clean --force

then npm start